Putting a Tkinter window below all other windows
I'm trying to make a Tkinter window appear below all other windows.
I know how to make it appear over all other windows:
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.attributes('-topmost', True)
root.mainloop()

But I'm trying to do the opposite of that - so that the window sits under all windows, on the desktop. -bottommost isn't a thing though, sadly.

Does the answer to this question help at all?

You can set up an event binding to lower the root window whenever it's focused:
import tkinter as tk


def send_to_back(_event) -> None:
    root.lower()


root = tk.Tk()
root.lower()  # start window in the back (may not be necessary)
root.bind('<FocusIn>', send_to_back)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root.mainloop()

FWIW, this won't place the window below (behind?) icons on the desktop, but it should keep it below all other windows, including those not created by your tkinter app.

tkinter manages only hierarchy of windows created by Tk, so You will need to use external libraries to manage system window level depth.
If You would like to You can minimalise window to taskbar, which in fact should also change display windows order.
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.wm_state('iconic') #same as root.lower()
root.mainloop()
# CTRL+C or CTRL+X to KeyboardInterrupt


This doesn't keep the root window below other windows, it just minimizes it to the taskbar. Once that window is maximized again it still behaves like a "regular" window.


I'm trying to make a Tkinter window appear below all other windows.

Here is code:
Snippet:
import tkinter as tk
 
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Keep Window on Top")
root.geometry("300x300")
 
top_window = tk.Toplevel(root)
top_window.title("Top Window")
top_window.geometry("200x200")
 
top_window.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)
 
root.mainloop()

The window sits under all windows.

This only keeps the TopLevel window above the root window. Both windows still behave like "regular" windows and will appear above other windows. The question wasn't "How do I keep a tkinter window above other tkinter windows" or inversely "how do I keep a tkinter window below other tkinter windows", it was "I'm trying to make a Tkinter window appear below all other windows."
